# Consulta SQL al hacer un Alter table. Error con una Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

He lanzado la siguiente consulta:

```
 ALTER TABLE sa_gac.Usuarios ALTER COLUMN Alias varchar(150)
```

Pero me da error me dice que hay una key que hay que modificar antes que se llama UQ_Usuarios_Alias.

No sé si tengo que hacer algo en cascada...  el error es el siguiente:

```
the object 'uq_usuarios_alias' is dependent on column 'alias'.
```

¿Qué hago?

ya me diréis!

info de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me da error de sintax el Change.

Comment: SQL Server es lo que uso.

Comment: EL change Column sigue dando error por el change.

Comment: Perdona, te estaba dando instrucciones para MySQL, elimino los comentarios y te añado la etiqueta a tu pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Si el campo que estas intentando modificar es campo clave (Primary Key) o tiene una referencia (Foreing Key) no te permitira hacerlo.

Lo que debes hacer es eliminar el **CONSTRAINT** que en tu caso es el objeto `uq_usuarios_alias` luego de ello podras modificar el campo `Alias` de tu tabla `sa_gac.Usuarios`, y posterior a eso vuelves a crear el **CONSTRAINT** `uq_usuarios_alias`

No conozco como estan definidas tus tablas por lo tanto te dejo aqui un ejemplo que debes ajustar para solventar tu problema:

**1. Eliminas el CONSTRAINT**

```
     ALTER TABLE PROPIETARIO.Nombre_Tabla DROP CONSTRAINT uq_usuarios_alias
```

**2. Alteras la TABLA**

```
     ALTER TABLE sa_gac.Usuarios ALTER COLUMN Alias varchar(150)
```

**3. Creas nuevamente el CONSTRAINT**. (te dejo dos ejemplos en caso que sea PRIMARY KEY O FOREING KEY)

-- Si es PRIMARY KEY

```
    ALTER TABLE [Nombre_Tabla] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [uq_usuarios_alias] PRIMARY KEY [campo]
```

-- Si es FOREING KEY

```
    ALTER TABLE [Nombre_Tabla] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [uq_usuarios_alias] FOREING KEY [campo]
    REFERENCES [Nombre_Tabla] (campo);
```

Comment: como  sé si es Foreign o Primary? El tema es que la tengo dentro de Keys.

Comment: y en el campo que debería de poner? ando algo perdida

Comment: Te lo coloque como ejemplo porque no tengo visibilidad de tus tablas, si puedes compartir la estructura de la tabla ``sa_gac.Usuarios`` y de las tablas que se relacionen con esa seria de mucha ayuda

Comment: Puedes ejecutar este comando para ver la informacion completa de una tabla ``EXEC sp_help 'sa_gac.Usuario';``

Comment: pongo una imagen arriba! :)

Comment: Con esa salida podemos ver que el constraint_name ``uq_usuarios_alias`` no pertenece a la tabla ``sa_gac.Usuario`` por lo tanto es muy problema que sea una foreing key de otra tabla que referencia a la tabla ``sa_gac.Usuario``. Tienes que mirar cuales tablas se relacionan con la tabla ``sa_gac.Usuario`` y por medio de sp_help poder ubicar cual tabla tiene el contrainst ``uq_usuarios_alias``